# Can't find Report Type:

Tags: custom-report-type

I can see this here:[image]

But I can not see it anywhere here:

[image]

Why is it now showing up in Setup>Report Types?

Comment: Might be part of some package?

Comment: Any way of finding out?

Comment: check installed packages section there would be report types in it

Comment: Nope, not in any of those...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a standard report type, created when you enable [Campaign Influence](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_setup.htm&type=5). It cannot be customized.

Answer (score 0):

The report type you are trying to find is a Standard report type which means it is created by Salesforce itself which can not be modified. 
In Setup>Report-type, you can only create/modify Custom report types. (Clearly mentioned on Header)
Would you have any specific requirement to achieve, please elaborate so we can help you out to achieve it?